# How to fetch date and time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string below.

```
Str= """Feb 11 22 error Start"
```

I need to check if ERROR is there in string above then print YES

I am new to python . plz help.

Comment: `date = ", ".join(Str.split(', ')[1:])`

Comment: Based on the limited information `' '.join(Str.split(' ')[-5:])`

Comment: @VasilisG. I need to restrict string below 22:17:31 Wed Feb 11, 2015 this line. How can I do that

Comment: Could you clarify that by updating your question with your desired output?

Comment: Updated it..plz check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to check if an error exists:

```
def checkError(Str):
    if 'ERROR' in Str:
        openBracket = Str.find('(')+1
        closedBracket = Str.find(')')
        status = "".join(Str[openBracket:closedBracket])
        error = "\n".join(['YES',", ".join(Str.split('\n\n')[2].split(', ')[1:]),status])
        return error
    else:
        return 'No errors found.'

error = checkError(Str)
print(error)
```

Output:

```
YES
22:17:31 Wed Feb 11, 2015
software ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included two different ways(i.e. `regex` and `find()`) to fetch desired elements a given string. One can use any method.

```
import re

def get_log(Str):
    if 'ERROR' in Str:
        date = re.search('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{3} \w{3} \d{2}, \d{4}', Str)
        error = Str[Str.find("(")+1:Str.find(")")]
        result = 'YES,\n'+date.group()+',\n'+error
        print(result)

get_log(Str)
```

Comment: Please try and add some commentary along with your code-only answer to explain why it might help the OP.